# DPLL algorithm - only advice

Tags: java, eclipse, algorithm

I have a problem. I'm implementing the DPLL algorithm (which I've already finished). Now I'm calculating the running time by the standard function java api.

```
System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The problem is that I have to provide the test results to my problem, but compared to all the sources that I found on the internet, my algorithm has run times considerably better. Now either I've found the best implementation of the algorithm ever (That rule it out), or the function returns a wrong time.

The time unit of the function is milliseconds (ms)? 
Thank you all.

Comment: What's the question again? Are you asking about [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis%28%29)?

Comment: because my algorithm has less time than others and what specifically does this phrase mean: "Returns the current time in milliseconds. note that while the unit of time of the return value is a millisecond, the granularity of the value depends on the underlying operating system and may be larger. For example, many operating systems measure time in units of tens of milliseconds. "

Comment: Try `nanoTime` and a current Java. currentTimeMillis sometimes may return the same value. Furthermore it is better to compare to oneself: larger datasets, so complexity shows etc.

Comment: maybe not my computer does not fit well the time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accuracy of `System.currentTimeMillis()` is rather bad (values hop in steps of dozends of milliseconds).

For benchmarking or precise timeing, better use `System.nanoTime()` instead, which does (other than currentTimeMillis) *not* represent a date/time, but rather a **time offset** (in nanoseconds, 10^-9 sec).

Comment: but this method return the time in nanosecond or always in millisecond?

Comment: It's all [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#nanoTime%28%29). "The value returned represents nanoseconds since some fixed but arbitrary origin time." Thus, you can't use it to measure *absolute time* (i.e. calendar date and time), but you can use it to measure *relative time* (i.e. time differences).